# Laravel Getting element from a parameter issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my Code to get the AuthorData from the AuthorModel

```
$AuthorData = AuthorModel::where('BlogAuthor', '=', '1')->get();
echo $AuthorData;
```

While i echo the $AuthorData

I am getting

```
[{"AutoId":1,"BlogAuthor":1,"AuthorName":"Raj Kumar","AuthorDesc":null,"CreatedAt":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdatedAt":null,"UpdatedBy":null,"IsDeletable":null,"Status":1}]
```

But while i try to get only the AuthorName like `echo $AuthorData->BlogAuthor;` below i am getting `Undefined property:` error.

What is the mistake i am doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get()` returns a collection. If you closely look at the output of the whole object you can see that it is being converted to an array `[...]`.

You probably only want the `first` result since only one should match

```
$AuthorData = AuthorModel::where('BlogAuthor', '=', '1')->first();
echo $AuthorData->AuthorName;
```

Or if you want all results you need to loop

```
$AuthorData = AuthorModel::where('BlogAuthor', '=', '1')->get();
foreach($AuthorData as $Author){
    echo $Author->AuthorName;
}
```